# How to process the different location of multiple files in parellel using spark with java?

Tags: java, apache-spark

can anybody help me to How to process the different location of multiple files in parallel using spark with java.

can anybody share the sample code.

Comment: I have sample code in scala, will you be able to understand scala ?

Comment: yes,you can share the code i will go through.

Answer (score 1):

- Create Callable class
- This would the load of dataframe from the file and cache it
- Driver class would Create an Executor Service with n thread where n>1
- Create list of Callable task
- Submit the list of call task using `executor.invokeAll`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class LoadDataFrameInParallel {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        List<String> filPaths = new ArrayList<>();
        SparkSession spark = Constant.getSparkSess();
        List<LoadDataFrame> futureList =  filPaths.stream().map( filePath -> new LoadDataFrame(spark,filePath)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(filPaths.size());
        List<Future<Dataset<String>>> output =  executor.invokeAll(futureList);
        output.forEach(future -> {
            try {
                future.get().count();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

}

class LoadDataFrame implements Callable<Dataset<String>> {

    private final SparkSession spark;
    private final String filePath;

    public LoadDataFrame(SparkSession spark, String filePath) {
        this.spark = spark;
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }

    @Override
    public Dataset<String> call() {
        return spark.read().textFile(filePath).cache();
    }}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the code,Can you share the tutorial for learning the spark with Java.It will be great helpful for me.

Comment: Was that the answer you were looking for ? I personally have downloaded the Latest Spark binary and have observed how the examples are implemented. Better start learning scala parallely so that you can convert code from  scala to java and vice versa

Comment: Thank you, It is very useful for me.

Comment: feel free to upvote and accept the answer @SudhakarKunchala

Answer (score 0):

Please note below code is in `scala`.

I have kept sample files in different folder each file will have one column.

```
// Files are available in different directories.

scala> "tree /tmp/data".!
/tmp/data
├── dira
│   └── part-00000-bc205041-1c5e-4a49-a55f-50df2a223bea-c000.snappy.orc
├── dirb
│   ├── dirba
│   │   └── part-00000-76b89d6f-9874-4b7e-828e-542e0f133af8-c000.snappy.orc
│   └── part-00000-5368c87e-f09e-4ef4-ab4a-687476ebf128-c000.snappy.orc
├── dirc
│   └── part-00000-c1d17495-e9c7-46c4-a11e-9c02ffa9c170-c000.snappy.orc
└── dird
    ├── dire
    │   └── part-00000-e78d344a-c0c8-4ec3-bef5-2bf556239e90-c000.snappy.orc
    └── part-00000-d89271e0-8689-4926-af10-579dff74b752-c000.snappy.orc

6 directories, 12 files

scala> val paths = Seq("/tmp/data/dira","/tmp/data/dirb","/tmp/data/dirb/dirba","tmp/data/dirc","/tmp/data/dird","/tmp/data/dird/dire") // Get these list dynamic, right now i am adding static list
paths: Seq[String] = List(/tmp/data/dira, /tmp/data/dirb, /tmp/data/dirb/dirba, tmp/data/dirc, /tmp/data/dird, /tmp/data/dird/dire)

scala> val dfr = spark.read.format("orc") // Creating DataFrameReader object once.
dfr: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader = org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader@23d34ed

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

spark.time {
  // using par to process parallel.
  paths.zipWithIndex.par.map{path => {
        println(s" Processing file - ${path._1} & Index - ${path._2}") // To show you parallel
        dfr.load(path._1)
    }
  }.reduce(_ union _).show(10,false)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

 Processing file - /tmp/data/dira & Index - 0
 Processing file - tmp/data/dirc & Index - 3
 Processing file - /tmp/data/dirb/dirba & Index - 2
 Processing file - /tmp/data/dirb & Index - 1
 Processing file - /tmp/data/dird & Index - 4
 Processing file - /tmp/data/dird/dire & Index - 5
+----+
|id  |
+----+
|1001|
|1002|
|1003|
|1004|
|1005|
|1006|
|1007|
|1008|
|1009|
|1010|
+----+
only showing top 10 rows

Time taken: 446 ms

scala>
```

Comment: Can you please accept question or upvote if it helps to solve issue.